# A Strange behavior of button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, event-handling

After start the application, i load content of formularzZgloszeniowy to empty div(#zawartoscTabeli). After click in li element, i load dates from div #ogloszenia to div(#zawartoscTabeli). From this moment, i can't catch event from button #kik.

Has someone any idea how to solve this problem??

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dokument bez tytułu</title>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#zawartoscTabeli').stop().css('opacity', '0').html($('#formularzZgloszeniowy').html()).animate({
            opacity: 1
        }, 500);

        $("section ul").on('click', 'li', function() {
            var id = this.id;
            $('#zawartoscTabeli').stop().css('opacity', '0').html($('#ogloszenia div:nth-child(' + id + ')').html()).animate({
                opacity: 1
            }, 500);
        });

        $('#kik').click(function() {
            alert('dddd');
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <section>
            <ul>
                <li id="1" style="font-size: 12px;">CLICK</li>
            </ul>
            <div id="zawartoscTabeli">
            </div>
        </section>
        <!--formularz zgloszeniowy-->
        <div id="formularzZgloszeniowy" style="display: none">
            <form id="form1" action="rejestracjaUzytkownika.jsp" method="POST">
                <div class="formualrz">
                    <div class="width20">Preferowane miejsce pracy<sup>*</sup>:</div>
                    <div class="width20">
                        <input type="text" name="miejsce_pracy" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="formualrz">
                    <div class="left">Imię i nazwisko<sup>*</sup>:</div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <input type="text" name="imie_nazwisko" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <BR/>
                <BR/>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--formularz zgloszeniowy-->
        <div id="ogloszenia" style="display: none">
            <div>
                <p class="bold">Opis stanowiska:</p>
                <ul>
                    <li>123</li>
                    <li>1234</li>
                    <li>326236</li>
                </ul>
                <button id="kik">BACK</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[Link to demo](http://jsfiddle.net/95v7fbbe/)

Answer (score 1):

As you're updating the `html` of element, the `events` are unbinded. Use `event delegation`:

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the future.

```
$('#zawartoscTabeli').on('click', '#kik', function () {
    alert('Łot de fack');
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/95v7fbbe/1/

Docs: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: Why DownVote? Please add comments here